# Webpack HtmlWebpackPlugin not displaying pages

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

I am new to webpack so this is probably something silly.

My current file structure is as follows

```
---src
------css
---------colors.sass
---------main.sass
------img
---------img1.png
------js
---------app.js
---------alert.js
---index.html
---test.html
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

### My webpack.config.js is as follows

```
//NPM
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var _ = require('underscore');

//Plugins
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

var extractPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: 'main.css'
});

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/js/app.js',
        alert: './src/js/alert.js'
    },
    devtool: 'eval',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8080,
        hot: true,
        noInfo: false,
        inline: true
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[hash].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['babel-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: __dirname
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                use: extractPlugin.extract({
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['html-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'img/'
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: '/'
                    }
                }],
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            chunks: ['app'],
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            chunks: ['alert'],
            filename: 'test.html',
            template: './src/test.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            _: "underscore"
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            // ...
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        extractPlugin
    ]
};
```

### My package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --inline --progress --colors",
        "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress --profile --colors",
        "prod": "webpack -p"
    },
```

In `app.js` & `alert.js` I simply have console logs. In `index.html` & `test.html` I just have a basic HTML5 layout and H1 tags with the page name.

I wanted to be able to go to `index.html` and only use `app.js` and in `test.html` to only use `alert.js`

Now, when I run `npm run start` I get the following appearing on the page, inside the body of the HTML.

```
module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "/index.html";
```

In the console, there are no errors but the console logs from either `app.js` or `alert.js` do appear, but the HTML doesn't render. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You defined two different rules for `.html` files.

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: ['html-loader']
},
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: '/'
        }
    }],
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html')
}
```

These two rules are conflicting (except for `./index.html`) and you might get an undesired result. `html-webpack-plugin` will also apply any configured loaders to the template file. In your case it applied the `file-loader` to it, which copies the file and returns a reference to it (the export you got), such that the copied file can be referenced in your HTML. That is definitely not what you want. The easiest solution is to remove the second rule and only keep the `html-loader`.

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: ['html-loader']
},
```

If you would like to use `file-loader` for any other HTML files, you can do it by making sure to not apply the configured loader to the templates. There are several different options, one of which is using a different extension and as `html-webpack-plugin` will apply an [EJS](https://github.com/mde/ejs) loader as a fallback if no loader is specified, you should use `.ejs`. See [The template option](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md) for other options.